# Инкремент и дикремент для подсчёта суммы билетов?

Tags: vue.js

подскажите как при увелечения количества билетов в кино или интремента - управлять ценной перед оплатой
Цена одного билета - 200

```
 <button @click="addCounter()">+</button>
 <button @click="incCounter()">-</button>
    {{counter}}
 <p>Price {{price}}</p>
```

Модель

```
counter: 0,
price: 200
```

Методы

```
addCounter() {
            this.counter++
            if (this.counter>=1) {
                this.price += 200
            }
        },
        incCounter() {

            if (this.counter>=0) {
                this.counter--
                this.price -= 200
            }
        }
```

Comment: Инкремент это и есть увеличение. Или я чего-то не понял? Уменьшение это декремент. А что не получается-то?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Имея цену за один билет, вы можете просто управлять счетчиком `counter` (количеством билетов), чтобы получать итоговую стоимость всех билетов, используя допустим [вычислительное свойство](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html):

```
computed: {
    totalPrice() {
      return this.counter * this.price
    }
  },
```

Полный пример:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      counter: 1,
      price: 200,
    }
  },
  computed: {
    totalPrice() {
      return this.counter * this.price
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addCounter() {
      this.counter++
    },
    incCounter() {
      this.counter--
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="addCounter">+</button>
  <button @click="incCounter" :disabled="counter < 1">-</button>
  <hr>Всего билетов - {{counter}}
  <p>Итоговая стоимость = {{totalPrice}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо но я уже решил )