# Подсчёт билетов в кино на Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js

Добрый день как сделать + - создания билетов в кино
Цена за один билет будет хранится в модела (может быть динамической)
выводить количество билетов кликнув на кнопки - +
И их цену

```
<div class="counter-increment" @click="incCounter()">-</div>
      <div>{{counter}}</div>
 <div class="counter-decrement" @click="addCounter()">+</div>


data() {return : {counter: 1, price: 30}}
```

Методы

```
addCounter() {
            if (this.counter < 17) {
                this.counter++
                if (this.counter >= 0) {
                    this.price += 120
                }
            }
        },
        incCounter() {
            if (this.counter > 0) {
                this.counter--
                this.price -= 120
            }
        }
```

Comment: А что не получилось? `@click="incCounter"` без скобок.

Comment: считает не коректно и у меня цена фиксорована, а я получаю с запроса

Comment: @babakov.roman678, вы не могли бы более корректно описать условия и суть проблемы?

Comment: Я хочу уведичивать количество билетов двумя кнопками (+, -), цену одного билета я получаю в response и присваиваю модели. Как релизовать такой функционал

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1195385/%d0%98%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82-%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%87%d1%91%d1%82%d0%b0-%d1%81%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%bc%d1%8b-%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2/1195402#1195402 - этот ответ не решил вашей задачи?

Comment: аа возможно, простите заработался - как связать с другой поделью например (кликаем на билеты и counter увеличивается, цена пересчитывается / так же второй клик чтобы забрать билет с бронирования)
Тоесть клик у меня организовать , не понимаю как связать этот пример и клик на билеты - чтобы всё это было динамически

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Инкремент и дикремент для подсчёта суммы билетов?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1195385/%d0%98%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82-%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%87%d1%91%d1%82%d0%b0-%d1%81%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%bc%d1%8b-%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2)